How do I object under GDPR to Microsoft GitHub sending me "free access to GitHub Copilot"?
Like millions of others, I've received a marketing email from Microsoft GitHub, "You have free access to GitHub Copilot" (announcement).
I didn't find a way to unsubscribe: the unsubscribe link only leads to a generic option in a SendGrid mailing list to opt out from "GitHub Transactional: Transactional emails from GitHub about products and accounts"; other opt-outs available are "Product News" and "GitHub Education".
Needless to say, I never consented to LLM marketing or any exposure to LLM products in the first place.
How do I exercise my GDPR rights to object? There are multiple rights but some are easier than others to exercise, so I want to focus on those which are most obviously legally enforceable in this case.
I currently have this draft, to be sent to privacy@github.com according to the section "Your Privacy Rights" of their privacy policy:

Dear GitHub,
I wish to exercise my rights under art. 15 of the GDPR to ask any relevant information on what led to my receipt of an email "You have free access to GitHub Copilot" (Message-ID: <@geopod-ismtpd-24>; Date: Wed, 18 Dec 2024 21:01:27 +0000).
For any data involved in said email and the decision it announces, please include information on:

its sources;
how long it's kept;
any other purposes it's used for;
how to object to said uses;
what uses or processes happen outside the EU/EEA;
any third parties involved.

I never consented to the sending of such marketing messages, and if any such consent was ever conveyed to you I hereby revoke it; allowing "transactional emails" shall not be construed as consent from me for such marketing emails.
I further object to the usage of automated decision-making processes to enlist my account for LLM products.
Yours truly,


"Hilariously", emailing privacy@github.com triggers an immediate response that:

IMPORTANT: Support Ticket Declined
We now require that new support requests be created using our Support website: https://support.github.com

Upon opening a form on that website, I'm immediately served a Copilot chatbot.

One thing you may want to reference while writing such a letter is the nightmare letter which is designed for data controllers to check they are able to fullfill an SAR.  It is worth noting GDPR SARs can be made to any member of an organisation.

@User65535 I don't know if it's a "nightmare letter" but yes, I'm indeed formulating an art. 15 request which is a subject access request.

The unsubscribe link unsubscribed me on clicking, what was the issue there? Yes, it unsubscribed me from "Transactional emails from GitHub about products and accounts", so that seems to  be the clever name they chose for their marketing emails, but whatever, it does seem to unsubscribe and works with a single click.

@terdon The issue is that I don't know what that optout does and how I was opted in. Also, new processors and new uses have been suddenly added for my personal data (I don't think I've ever received a SendGrid email from GitHub before; their usual transactional emails come from smtp.github.com through a Microsoft SMTP server). So I want to know what's going on.

SendGrid is just a tool to track what happens to an email after it is sent for marketing purposes. They likely just changed how they send these types of emails.

It's not "needless to say" that you never consented to this communication, since people often click through terms of service and end-user licence agreements without carefully reading them. Do you, in fact, have a GitHub account or a Microsoft account, or have you ever agreed to a Microsoft software licence? If so, did you check the terms to see whether they required you to consent to receive marketing e-mails such as this? If they did require such consent, did you subsequently notify them that you were withdrawing it?

If you decide not to unsubscribe from the options when you deliberately went to a page designed primarily and clearly to give you an opportunity to do so, you may be on weaker ground going forward.  That will not make up for the past, but it may weaken any claim you make in future if you avoided the opportunity to minimise the continuing damage.

Do you have a problem with GitHub sending email about their products generally, or it's because of LLM specifically? If it's the latter, then I don't think that's feasible if GitHub doesn't provide an option to break their transactional emails into more granular interests.

"usage of automated decision-making processes to enlist my account for LLM products." I doubt it's an automated decision-making processes, rather than GitHub sending this to everyone who has an account on GitHub.

@JoeW No, they didn't change. Later transactional emails still use the same method as previously.

@AndrewT. It's possible but we don't know for sure. They mentioned 150 million accounts, I don't think that's all accounts. It is our right to find out.

@Psychonaut Yes I did read the privacy policy and no it is not possible that I accidentally gave consent. To learn about valid consent under GDPR, you can read https://www.edpb.europa.eu/our-work-tools/our-documents/guidelines/guidelines-052020-consent-under-regulation-2016679_en

They are not required to use the same method for sending every single email. SendGrid is just a way to track what happens to an email after it is sent and a company doesn't need to use it for every single email they send. They just must have reasons for tracking what happens to this email such as how many people open it and do things such as click on the links in the email.

I never said they would be required to use the same method for everything.

By the way the closure reason for this question is blatantly incorrect. A questions about a general legal issue affecting 150 million people is obviously in scope, just like https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/28180/how-does-ses-arbitration-clause-hold-up-under-the-gdpr .
